# SVN merge with renamed file results in tree conflict

Tags: svn, merge

I created branch from my working copy. In it I renamed the file using `svn rename` and made some modifications to it. Then I commited the file which commited with status A, and the old file was scheduled for delete. My problem occured when I tried to merge that commit to my working copy. I've got tree conflict on merge. Tree conflict appeared on file which I renamed in branch. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the ***exact*** error message you're getting? That'll help us resolve the issue.

Comment: @DavidW - `local file edit, incoming file delete upon merge` was the message. So file is deleted in branch but it exists on trunk(and on my working copy). I couldn't solve this in a logic way, so I postponed tree conflict, and then reverted file which was in conflict(the deleted file in branch).  After revert file was in no conflict, but it was excessive now so i just deleted it using svn del. It solved my problem.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke - I don't think this is duplicate question, the link you posted offers too general topic, and solution it offers it to just accept working copy...

Comment: @SrdjanMladjan _Local file edit_?. That may be your issue. Subversion noticed the file was edited on one branch, but modified on the other. The conflict is whether you want the edit or delete the file. You can delete the file locally, and then use `svn resolved` to mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "merge that commit into your *working copy*" you mean "merge that commit into *the trunk* (or some other branch)" right?

If that's true, your steps sound correct. I've seen this happen for a few reasons; a change to the branch you are merging into (someone else doing a rename, etc.) and yes, with older SVN tools, there were some times where the order of the operations were committed in a way that caused it.

In all cases, all you need to do is accept the rename and/or delete in your merge to resolve the conflict. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559929/resolving-tree-conflict) for how to resolve it.

Comment: On merge I meant - merge on trunk. I'll try creating another branch and merge the files from first branch to it. Maybe then merge on trunk will be successful.