# TortoiseSVN "tree conflict" on file when merging

Tags: svn-merge, tree-conflict

I have a directory in my trunk (trunk/gray/catalog/web/app_code/), and my branch (branches/125/gray/catalog/web/app_code/). The trunk and branch contain 8 files common to both, but the branch has 20 files not found in trunk. These files were SVN added to the branch. Both directories only contain files as children (no children directories). gray/catalog/web/app_code/ was made in the branch and trunk separately with SVN Add.

When I attempt to Test merge branches/125/gray/catalog/web/app_code/ to trunk/gray/catalog/web/app_code/ using Tortoise SVN all of the common files show tree conflict errors, and the files in branch but not in trunk are not added to trunk.

If I attempt the test merge to/from at the gray/catalog/web/ level then no conflicts are shown. The 8 files which are common are shown as being SVN adds, and the 20 files in branch but not in trunk are not added or mentioned at all.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is beyond stating the obvious, but most of my tree conflicts stem from having renamed things and SVN gets riled up.

Were these files renamed multiple times? or possibly all copy pasted?

Typically these are highly annoying, but fixable by tricking SVN. Either using a switch command, or creating the files anew.

[Resolving tree conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559929/resolving-tree-conflict)
[Why am I getting tree conflicts in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/why-am-i-getting-tree-conflicts-in-subversion)